# Postgresql stops logging in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, logging

I am using postgres 12.12 via the official docker image and it sometimes stops logging, seemingly randomly. I am trying to figure out what could be causing this.

I'm running it on my development laptop via a docker compose file, like `docker-compose start my-postgres`.
It's working fine, logging as expected, so that `docker logs -f <container-name>` shows something like:

```
2023-01-09 09:05:42.860 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.12 (Debian 12.12-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2023-01-09 09:05:42.860 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-01-09 09:05:42.861 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-01-09 09:05:42.867 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-01-09 09:05:47.883 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
...
```

However, today while looking into a bug, I noticed the logs stop:

```
2023-02-02 16:01:50.588 UTC [36755] WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
2023-02-02 16:01:50.785 UTC [36755] WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
```

The last line above is more or less the time I stopped working on postgres, and put the laptop to sleep shortly after.

Nothing is logged between the extracts above and below, although the db is running and responds to queries after waking up my laptop. There is no hardware power down during that period.

Below is when I restart the container with `docker-compose restart my-postgres`:

```
2023-02-06 16:49:57.062 UTC [1] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-02-06 16:49:57.072 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-02-06 16:49:57.073 UTC [15623] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-02-06 16:49:57.075 UTC [43191] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-02-06 16:49:57.077 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 32) exited with exit code 1
2023-02-06 16:49:57.082 UTC [27] LOG:  shutting down
2023-02-06 16:49:57.141 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

It then goes on to restart, issuing the same logs as at the top of my post.

This tells me the logging mechanism is still working, but somehow is interrupted. I have seen this behaviour several times with postgres/docker, but I've never managed to figure out what the cause is.

I'm running the official docker image, with no special config besides `shm_size: 512m` in the compose file. The host is debian/linux if it matters.

Is there anything obvious that I should look at to fix this?

Comment: Maybe there was just nothing to log.  Unless you have non-default log settings, merely running and responding to queries doesn't cause log messages.  Were there specific messages you were expecting to see?

Comment: I was expecting something to log, because I was running the same app code that caused the warnings about transactions in progress I mentioned above. Running that same code again after restarting the postgres container did log them again.

Comment: Maybe the problem in your app is transient.  You should do something more definitive than that, like maybe inject intentional syntax errors occasionally.  Or turn log_statement to 'all', which would not only more robustly verify the logging is working, but might help find the problem as well.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. It sounds like a reasonable approach indeed. Thanks!